# Hyperdeterminant of 4x4x4 hypermatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products

If given the hypermatrix (which I've written here in bracket notation since I'm not all too sure how to display this)
{
{{1,1,1,1},{1,1,-1,-1},{1,-1,-1,1},{1,-1,1,-1}},
{{1,1,1,1},{1,1,-1,-1},{1,-1,1,-1},{1,-1,-1,1}},
{{1,1,1,1},{1,-1,1,-1},{1,1,-1,-1},{1,-1,-1,1}},
{{1,-1,1,-1},{1,1,1,1},{1,1,-1,-1},{1,-1,-1,1}}
}

how would one go about calculating the hyperdeterminant? I know of Cayley's second hyperdeterminant formula for a 2x2x2 cube, however how would one calculate the tensor product for an even numbered dimension other than 2?

Comment: Fascinating. I've never heard of this. Perhaps https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.0472v1.pdf is of use to you. I see several explicit calculations of small-dimensional cases. If nobody picks up on your question in a day or two, I'd recommend you try MO for this one.

Comment: I saw this PDF as well, @JamesS.Cook. It's quite the mouthful.

Comment: It is divisible by 32 (obtained after some SL(4)×SL(4)×SL(4) linear transformations)